# Rows Are Duplicated in WEBI Report

Tags: sql, webi

WEBI Report is created with a structure, so I cannot modify the cells one by one but I need that.
I use `[Things] where ([Things]="Thing")` etc. in cells. However it looks like this, the rows are duplicated for a reason:

[image]

but i want this:

[image]

any help is appreciated.
ps: i cannot give the actual data cause its a customer's report.

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking SQL questions.

Comment: If you could provide a free-hand SQL that replicates the issue, I'll dig into it when I can find some time.

Answer (score 0):

In your example case, it's not obvious what you want because your starting data is not clear. It's also not obvious where the #MULTIVALUE sits in the block, i.e. as a sub total. If it is a subtotal, then it suggests that [Quantity] is not defined as a measure. If that is the case, =Sum( whatever is in the multivalue cell ) will fix that, assuming it is a number and not text held as a number. If it's text, then create a new variable, called say, NumericQuantity, as =ToNumber([Quantity]) and use that instead.

Without knowing the actual structure of the block, that's the best advice that I can offer.